# Stacked BarChart in MPAndroid Chart Library

Tags: android, graph, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid chart library to show some results into stackbar chart. I am able to create stackedbar chart. But I am facing problems in labeling of bars. I have data of different years and months. I want to label data month wise according to year. I am attaching a picture here to give you better idea, what i want to achieve.I want to label my graph just like in sample picture. I want months divided according to years.

[image]